# Xcode search bar is not in table header view if I change the constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, tableview, uisearchbar

I want to make a search bar at the top of table view
and I want to change a location of table view when I clicked a button.

(I used this code to make search bar)

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)   
table.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

So I changed the constraints and It moved.

But the problem is if search is active, search bar does not follow the table view. And if I click the cancel button, it follows.

Why does it happen? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

How did you created your Search Bar? I'm just working with it and created like this:

[image: Search Bar example]

I've added a `Table View` to my scene and added the `Search Bar and Search Display Controller` to it. I've also added the following code to my `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.processTableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.processTableView setDataSource:self];

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.processTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
}
```

Using it like this I've the expected behavior for the Search Bar. Is this what you looking to achieve?

[image]